# UK - Sweden Covid-19 Comparison

Tags: covid-19, virus, coronavirus, epidemiology

I compared Covid-19 data on the 17th of October 2020, using this source: https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html

```
UK population = 66650000 
Uk cases = 708297 
UK deaths = 43669
66650000 / 708297 = 1 positive on each 94 people
66650000 / 43669 = 1 death on each 1526 people

Sweden population = 10230000
Sweden cases = 103200
Sweden deaths = 5918
10230000 / 103200 = 1 positive on each 99 people
10230000 / 5918 = 1 death on each 1728 people
```

**Conclusion**: there are fewer cases and fewer deaths in Sweden, although they didn't do any lockdown and they didn't impose any restrictions.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: You might want to investigate how dense the population of the UK is compared to Sweden. Sweden is basically one big city surrounded by huge sparsely populated rural areas.